# Showing variable values on a 3D Plot

Tags: plotting, labeling, variable, display

I am running a 3D plot a 100 times to show the dynamics of two undetermined variables (`cM` and `cR`) for a 100 values of `cS`, using the following command:

```
Table[
 Plot3D[
  CentralizationBenefitSharingGraph[cM, cR, cS]
  , {cM, 0, 1}
  , {cR, 0, 1}
  , ViewPoint -> Above
  , PlotRange -> Automatic
  , AxesLabel -> Automatic
  , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
  , ColorFunction -> (If[#3 > 0, Green, Red] &)
  , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
  , PlotPoints -> 100
  , FaceGrids -> {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0}}
  , FaceGridsStyle -> Black
  , AxesStyle -> Thick
  , BoxStyle -> Thick
  ]
 , {cS, 0, 1, 1/100}
 ]
```

Awfully long, sorry about that. What I am trying to do, however, is show the corresponding value of the variable `cS` in every plotted graph, so that I won't have to manually add them a hundred times.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `PlotLabel`:

```
Table[Plot3D[Sin[(cM + cR + cS) 2 Pi], {cM, 0, 1}, {cR, 0, 1}, 
  ViewPoint -> Above, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> (HoldForm[Sin[(cM + cR + z) 2 Pi]] /. z -> cS), 
  ColorFunction -> (If[#3 > 0, Green, Red] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  FaceGrids -> {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0}}, 
  FaceGridsStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
  BoxStyle -> Thick], {cS, 0, 1, 1/3}]
```

[image]

Use, `PlotLabel -> Row[{"cS = ", cS}]` to get
[image]

Comment: The second code did the trick, thanks!

Is there any way though to show the fraction as a decimal?

Comment: @Joep, you can use, for example, `PlotLabel -> Row[{"cS = ", Round[cS, .001]}]` to show the three digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{
   Plot3D[
    Exp[-((cM + cR)/(0.1 + cS))^2]
    , {cM, 0, 1}
    , {cR, 0, 1}
    , ViewPoint -> Above
    , PlotRange -> Automatic
    , AxesLabel -> Automatic
    , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
    , ColorFunction -> (If[#3 > 0, Green, Red] &)
    , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
    , PlotPoints -> 100
    , FaceGrids -> {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0}}
    , FaceGridsStyle -> Black
    , AxesStyle -> Thick
    , BoxStyle -> Thick
    , PlotLabel -> StringTemplate["cS: ``"]@cS
    , ImageSize -> 400
    ],
   VerticalGauge[cS, {0, 1}]
   }
 , {cS, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]